# How to gain a function of an estimated density?

Tags: r, function

How do I save the result from density(dataset) as a function?
So then if I want to evaluate point x in that function, it gives me the probability from that density(dataset)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see below, `density` function retuns a list containing `x` and `y` values of density function which can be used to create a "interpolation" function using `approxfun` function.

```
d <- density(rnorm(100))

str(d)
## List of 7
##  $ x        : num [1:512] -3.85 -3.83 -3.82 -3.8 -3.79 ...
##  $ y        : num [1:512] 0.000135 0.000154 0.000176 0.0002 0.000227 ...
##  $ bw       : num 0.332
##  $ n        : int 100
##  $ call     : language density.default(x = rnorm(100))
##  $ data.name: chr "rnorm(100)"
##  $ has.na   : logi FALSE
##  - attr(*, "class")= chr "density"


pdf <- approxfun(d)


pdf(2)
## [1] 0.05439069
```

`approxfun` gives linear approximation

To verify  lets plot the original density `d`

```
plot(d)
```

[image]

Now lets plot the interpolated values using the new function `pdf` that we created

```
x <- seq(-2,2,by=0.01)

points(x, pdf(x))
```

[image]

Comment: density is already an estimation - to approximate further might cause more trouble than good.

Comment: @Яaffael indeed. But that's what OP asked.

Comment: I guess that is something one might have different takes on. The OP doesn't even know what a density really is - judging from his question. So, taking the question literal might not be the best choice. Additionally he just asks for a function - not for an approximation of an estimation.

Comment: Thanks! that it's precisely what I needed. I am sorry for the confusion, but I meant to use the function and I got confused on the density and probability itself.

Answer (score 2):

(The value of a density at a specific point is NOT the probability of that point.)

```
> d <- density(sample(10,1000000,replace=TRUE,prob=(1:10)/sum(1:10)))
> plot(d)

# the density is estimated at a specified number of points. I find the closest to
# the point I want to know the density's value of and then get that value.

> fd <- function(x) d$y[which.min(abs(d$x - x))]
> fd(6)
[1] 0.311895
```

[image]