# Efficiently find empirical density() for many arbitrary sample values (like dnorm(), but for empirical distribution)

Tags: r, kernel-density, probability-density, mapply

Say you've defined an empirical density (`sample.density`) for a sample of `x.sample` as in the following:

```
set.seed(1)
x.sample <- rnorm(100)
sample.density <- density(x.sample)
```

Now say that we have a gradient, `G`, for which we would like to know the expected densities

```
G <- seq(-2,2, length.out=20)
```

Based on the empirical distribution `sample.density`, what is the density of each value in `G`?

If I use a `for()` loop, I can get the answers like this:

```
G.dens <- c()
for(i in 1:length(G)){
    t.G <- G[i]
    G.dens[i] <- sample.density$y[which.min(abs(sample.density$x-t.G))]
}
```

The overarching idea is to do something like `dnorm()`, but instead of assuming that `x` is normally distributed with specified mean and s.d., I'd like to use a distribution determined empirically from an arbitrary sample (that isn't necessarily normal or any other well-described distribution that would be in the stats package).

Comment: I think this is what you're after: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24957905/retrieve-y-value-from-density-function-of-given-x-value/24958001#24958001

Comment: Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28077500/find-the-probability-density-of-a-new-data-point-using-density-function-in-r/28078265#28078265

Comment: Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22476542/how-to-gain-a-function-of-an-estimated-density/22477079#22477079. What did you search for that didn't find these? Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, many points at once! In your first comment linking to your answer, it's like finding the density for many blue dots. Instead of `approxfun` I am using a `which.min`, which isn't vectorized. I'll be finding the density of a *lot* of points, so I want this to be a vectorized operation. note that my for() loop answer does give the correct answer, 1 point at a time, as in your linked questions.

Comment: `approxfun()` does return a vectorized function: `ds<-with(sample.density, approxfun(x,y)); ds(seq(-2,2, length.out=20))`. Do you not want linear interpolation? You can use `method="constant"` to get something more like your implementation.

Comment: Ah, thank you! That third link provides the approach I needed ... I hadn't tried using `approxfun` actually b/c I wasn't familiar with it. Because that approximation is vectorized, it avoids the trouble of which.min, to find the closest matching element, because which.min cannot return several indices. Thanks. I'll just delete this question, as I think it duplicates that last link. I'd been searching for "empirical density" a lot. @MrFlick

Comment: @MrFlick I emphasized efficiency in the question title now, and provided an answer comparing speeds of the 3 approaches that I used. The one you suggested was the fastest. I don't think any of the answers you linked compared how to do this quickly, so I figure this contributes in a new way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the comment by @MrFlick pointed me in the right direction. In addition to the suggested `approxfun` approach and my example `for` loop approach, I also realized I could use `mapply`. Note that my use of `approxfun` won't exactly match the result by the 2 other approaches which use `which.min`, but I'm not concerned with that difference in output too much, although others might be.

```
First, reproducing the sample data from the question:
set.seed(1)
x.sample <- rnorm(100)
sample.density <- density(x.sample)
G <- seq(-2,2, length.out=20)
```

Now, create a function for the loop version

## loop()

```
loop <- function(x, ref){
    if(class(ref)!="density"){
        ref <- density(ref)
    }

    ref.y <- ref$y
    ref.x <- ref$x

    G.dens <- c()
    for(i in 1:length(x)){
        t.G <- x[i]
        G.dens[i] <- ref.y[which.min(abs(ref.x-t.G))]
    }

    G.dens
}
```

Next, I'll use the approach I came up with that uses `mapply`

## dsample()

```
dsample <- function(x, ref){

    if(class(ref)!="density"){
        ref <- density(ref)
    }

    XisY <- function(x,y){ # which of several X values most closely matches a single Y value?
        which.min(abs(y-x))
    }

    ref.y <- ref$y
    ref.x <- ref$x

    # ds <- approxfun(ref)

    # ds(x)

    ref.y[mapply(XisY, x, MoreArgs=list(y=ref.x))]
}
```

Finally, the approach harnessing `approxfun` as suggested by @MrFlick:

## af()

```
af <- function(x, ref){
    if(class(ref)!="density"){
        ref <- density(ref)
    }

    # XisY <- function(x,y){ # which of several X values most closely matches a single Y value?
    #   which.min(abs(y-x))
    # }

    ref.y <- ref$y
    ref.x <- ref$x

    ds <- approxfun(ref)

    ds(x)

    # ref.y[mapply(XisY, x, MoreArgs=list(y=ref.x))]
}
```

## Now to compare their speed:

```
microbenchmark(
    loop(G, sample.density),
    dsample(G, sample.density),
    af(G, sample.density)
)
# Unit: microseconds
#                        expr     min       lq     mean  median       uq      max neval
#     loop(G, sample.density) 221.801 286.6675 360.3698 348.065 409.9785  942.071   100
#  dsample(G, sample.density) 252.641 290.7900 359.0432 368.388 417.1510  520.960   100
#       af(G, sample.density) 201.331 227.8740 276.0425 253.339 273.6225 2545.081   100
```

## Now compare speed as the size of G increases:

```
speed.loop <- c()
speed.dsample <- c()
speed.af <- c()
lengths <- seq(20, 5E3, by=200)
for(i in 1:length(lengths)){
    G <- seq(-2,2, length.out=lengths[i])
    bm <- microbenchmark(
        loop(G, sample.density),
        dsample(G, sample.density),
        af(G, sample.density), times=10
    )

    means <- aggregate(bm$time, by=list(bm$expr), FUN=mean)[,"x"]/1E6 # in milliseconds
    speed.loop[i] <- means[1]
    speed.dsample[i] <- means[2]
    speed.af[i] <- means[3]


}

speed.ylim <- range(c(speed.loop, speed.dsample, speed.af))
plot(lengths, (speed.loop), ylim=(speed.ylim), type="l", ylab="Time (milliseconds)", xlab="# Elements in G")
lines(lengths, (speed.dsample), col="red")
lines(lengths, (speed.af), col="blue")
```

[image]